# how to check a link is present with href in component in writing jest test cases

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I do have a component that do have link with `href` and buttons.
I just need to write the spec file for the same component to make sure that everything like `href` and button with name is present in the `DOM`

```jsx
it('should check cancel link is availabe', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<RoomDetails {...defaultProps} />);
     var rendered = wrapper.find('<a>').render();
     expect(rendered.htmlProp('href')).toEqual('https:example.com/change')
});
```

Comment: any help will be highly appreciated..

Comment: Do you use Enzyme or react-testing-library ?

Comment: Enzyme is used .import { render,shallow } from 'enzyme';

Answer (score 0):

```js
it('should check cancel link is availabe', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<RoomDetails {...defaultProps} />);
         var anchorHref = wrapper.find('<a>').prop('href');
         expect(anchorHref).toEqual('https:example.com/change')
    });
```

Comment: am getting this error :Failed to parse selector: <a>. Just one thing ,i do have almost 4 <a> tag in my component

Comment: you can do `wrapper.find('<a>').at(numberofanchortag).prop('href')`

Comment: `expect(wrapper.find('a').at(numberOfTheAnchorTagYouWantToTest).prop('href')).to.equal('/yourPath');`

Comment: its <a> or a. i am bit confused

Comment: In .find() method you can find by class, id, or just simple html tags, like I did, I never tried to do it using `<a>`, probably it works the same as `a` I don't know, try it in both ways, probably is the same outcome.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolae for the quick work.. but am facing some error **Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.**

Comment: **expect(wrapper.find('.buttonWrapper-ns>a').prop('href')).to.equal('/myPath');**-This is my code,but am facing the above error.

Comment: You are facing that because you have 4 nodes as you stated, that you have 4 anchor tag elements, you have to select the one that you want to test, add a class to that and do find(".testedAnchorClass").prop....